# display Conjugate[...] as superscript star

Tags: output-formatting, complex, display

For some complex expressions, I want to display the `Conjugate[x]` as $x^*$ (keyboard input as esc-conj-esc) to make the expression cleaner. I can get the desired display with `TraditionalForm[...]` but I would like to make the expressions easy to copy-paste for part of the calculation later and `TraditionalForm[...]` transforms function `foo[x]` to `foo(x)` which may be problematic. `/. {Conjugate[x] -> x\[Conjugate]}` leave the expression untouched. I guess I need to hold the star-superscript so mathematica does not treat it as `Conjugate` when displaying and then unhold the pattern. How can this be done? The documenation for `HoldPattern` is not too clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the formatting for [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate):

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: MakeBoxes[Conjugate[x_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[
    {Parenthesize[x, StandardForm, Power]},
    "Conjugate",
    DisplayFunction->(SuperscriptBox[#1,"*"]&)
]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

I used a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) so that copy/paste works as expected. Examples:

```
Conjugate[x]
Conjugate[a+x]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! on my mathematica ver 11.0, `Parenthesize` is missing from the documentation, and the frontend thinks `Parenthesize` is missing the fourth argument "group" and shows a highlight with red "^" for the Parenthesize fucntion, but the code runs without problem.

Comment: I've definitely seen more `TemplateBoxes` in your answers than I'd ever seen before. I like it. My mind does not immediately run to `TemplateBox`, but of course it's super convenient.